# Is there a way to detect whether user is on wifi or cellular data with javascript?

Tags: javascript, connection, navigator

I want the video to autoplay on the website only if the user is connected to the wifi. I know about the navigator.connection api - but it's not available on safari, and besides it only tells you about the speed of the connection not the type.

Comment: A similar question was asked here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25968020/how-to-detect-the-mobile-connection-is-2g-3g-wifi-using-javascript Hope that's helpful!

Answer (score 4):

As of December 2020, Safari has made no moves to implement [the Network Information API](https://wicg.github.io/netinfo/), which as you've noted, provides the `navigator.connection` [`NetworkInformation` object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NetworkInformation). That's a shame, because other browsers have supplied this for years.

This means there is no equivalent of the iOS-native Reachability APIs on mobile Safari (or desktop Safari, for that matter), so the best you can do is to use a *very* rough hack like:

- looking up the user's public IP and trying to match it to a database of cell providers, or
- making a test download to roughly gauge connection speed.

For the sake of completeness, [according to the MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/connection), the browsers that *do* provide `navigator.connection` as of December 2020, are:

- Desktop:

  - Chrome 61+
  - Edge 79+
  - Firefox, but *only* if the user has enabled the `dom.netinfo.enabled` preference
  - Opera
- Mobile:

  - Android WebView 50+
  - Chrome Android 38+
  - Firefox Android 14+ (same caveat as desktop)
  - Opera Android 37+
  - Samsung Internet 3+

(Safari and Internet Explorer are the only major browsers conspicuously missing support.)

Comment: More compatibility info: https://caniuse.com/mdn-api_navigator_connection